# Index & Match in Ms Excel without Unique ID in the source sheet

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9P5G.png)

Hi there,
I have a queston about index & match function in Ms Excel.
How to find Emp ID if we dont have Unique ID in the source sheet?
in my thinking, it will use Index & Match function in Excel but I dont know how to get it.
Thank you in advance.

Gugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Email` from first table on column `D` then you can use it as a reference to get the `EMP ID`.
Just add this formula: `=INDEX('Master List Employee'!A:A,MATCH(D1,'Master List Employee'!E:E,0))`

**Alternative**
If you want to have the reference `Last Name`, `First Name` and `E-mail` together, in case  you could have some duplicates, you can have those parameters as references:

`=INDEX('Master List Employee'!A:A,MATCH(1,(A1='Master List Employee'!B:B)*(B1='Master List Employee'!C:C)*(D1='Master List Employee'!E:E),0))`
When your done with the formula, don't press `ENTER`, instead you press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to transform a normal formula into an array formula.

Comment: It's briliant. Thank you BOB. You really help me.

Comment: Glad i could help. Anyway I edit the post with an alternative way, check it.